# Is it wrong to say "house of wood" to mean that a house is built/made out of wood?

Tags: word-choice

To me, "house of wood" seems to refer more properly to a place where one can get stuff made out of wood, like "house of pizza" would refer to a place where one could find pizza, and not to a place made out of pizza.

However, "pizza house" can also be used to refer to a place that sells pizza, while "wood house" starts to feel like it might also refer to a house made out of wood.

It seems that the only 100% correct answers are "wooden house", or "house built/made out of wood", but I wouldn't know how to explain why "wood house" or "house of wood" cannot mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As beauty is in the eye of the beholder, so **house of wood** is in the mind of the interpreter.

It could be the name of a company selling timber. It could refer to a house that is made of wood. Or, in the case of a friend of mine, whose surname is Wood, it could refer to a house belonging to Wood. Indeed, his house was so named.

**Wood House** sounds like the name for an institution of some kind, possibly one named after a Mr/Ms Wood.

Only the phrases **wooden house** or **house made of wood** make it clear that the house is made of wood.

Comment: And a house enclosed by wood from all directions (such as a house inside a forest) ?